# C++: vector<string> does not match regex

Tags: c++

I really don't know what is wrong that my regex is not matching.

I tried two codes:

**Code1 (NOT MATCH):**

I am pushing from file to `vector<string> cn`;

```
  //FILE
  ifstream file(params.file_name);
  string line;
  // read each line of the file
  while ( getline(file, line) ){

    istringstream iss(line);
    string token;
    unsigned int loopCsv = 0;
    while (getline(iss, token, ';')){ //when ";" separate cn;uid;mail
      if (loopCsv == 0)
        cn.push_back(token); //cn
      if (loopCsv == 1)
        uid.push_back(token); //uid
      if (loopCsv == 2)
        mail.push_back(token); //mail
      loopCsv++;
      if (loopCsv == 3) //after 3 (cn,uid,mail) repeat
        loopCsv=0;
    }
  }
```

then trying regex:

```
cout << "There is Neruda Jakub: " << cn[286] << endl;
regex regexX(".*Jakub", std::regex::ECMAScript | std::regex::icase);
bool match = regex_search(cn[286], regexX);
if (match)
  cout << "MATCH!" << endl;
```

**I am getting output:**
There is Neruda Jakub: Neruda Jakub

but no match. I have also tried adding some symbols around cn[286] if there isn't any space |Neruda Jakub| and there isn't

**Code2 (MATCH):**

```
vector<string> someVctr;
someVctr.push_back("Neruda Jakub");
regex regexX(".*Jakub", std::regex::ECMAScript | std::regex::icase);
bool match = regex_search(someVctr[0], regexX);
if (match)
 cout << "MATCH!" << endl;
```

without problem, I will get MATCH!

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: looks like a typo in your Code2 sample, `nieco` vs `someVctr`

Comment: What character encoding is the file that you are reading from? There could be non-latin characters that are displayed like `J`, `a`, `k`, `u`, and/or `b`

Comment: @AndersK. yes just typo here, in code I have someVctr there too

Comment: @Caleth THANKS so much! ....it was utf-16... I totally forgot about something like formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, it looks like the file was encoded as `utf-16`. The simple fix for all of this is to replace all the `char` streams and strings with `char16_t` (or `wchar_t` on Windows)

```
basic_string<char16_t> cn;
basic_string<char16_t> uid;
basic_string<char16_t> mail;

//FILE
basic_ifstream<char16_t> file(params.file_name);
basic_string<char16_t> line;
// read each line of the file
while ( getline(file, line) ){

  basic_istringstream<char16_t> iss(line);
  basic_string<char16_t> token;
  unsigned int loopCsv = 0;
  while (getline(iss, token, ';')){ //when ";" separate cn;uid;mail
    if (loopCsv == 0)
      cn.push_back(token); //cn
    if (loopCsv == 1)
      uid.push_back(token); //uid
    if (loopCsv == 2)
      mail.push_back(token); //mail
    loopCsv++;
    if (loopCsv == 3) //after 3 (cn,uid,mail) repeat
      loopCsv=0;
  }
}

cout << "There is Neruda Jakub: " << cn[286] << endl;
basic_regex<char16_t> regexX(".*Jakub", std::regex::ECMAScript | std::regex::icase);
bool match = regex_search(cn[286], regexX);
if (match)
  cout << "MATCH!" << endl;
```